# layout UILabel after assigning a value for attributedString property

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that returns `NSMutableAttributedString` to style a `UILabel` in `UITableViewCell`.

To solve this issue, I run that code in main thread as following

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.titleLabel.attributedText = UITableViewCell.timelineTitle(prefix: "#Meeting: ", title: title, prefixColor: UIColor(hex: "#FF3B71"))
}
```

but now, the titleLabel start acquiring bigger space. It looks like cells are not re-calculate cell layout. `label.sizeToFit()` doesn't fix the issue!

Comment: Where do you call this part of code?

Comment: @mbabaev in configuring the cell when cell for row at is called

Comment: Not sure, but you can try to set attributedString inside tableViewWillDisplayCell....